# Issue with Jquery closest

Tags: jquery

What I would like is for the .alpha class span to be selected via the closest selector and the number inside of that to change however I cannot get this to work.

**HTML**

```
<h4>
    <span class="c1-rgba"></span>
    <span class="alpha">0.0</span>
    <input class="increaseAlpha" type="button" name="increase" value="+">
    <input class="decreaseAlpha" type="button" name="decrease" value="-">
</h4>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $(".increaseAlpha").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('span').text(  ( Math.min(1, Number($(".alpha").text()) + 0.1)).toFixed(1) )
    });
});
```

Comment: closest is used for ancestor selection not sibling selection

Comment: Would probably help if you read the documentation on closest()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.alpha` is not the closest element of `.increaseAlpha`. It is the sibling of `.increaseAlpha`. Try like following using `siblings()` method.

```js
$(".increaseAlpha").click(function() {
    var alpha  = $(this).siblings('span.alpha');
    alpha.text((Math.min(1, Number(alpha.text()) + 0.1)).toFixed(1))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>
    <span class="c1-rgba"></span>
    <span class="alpha">0.0</span>
    <input class="increaseAlpha" type="button" name="increase" value="+">
    <input class="decreaseAlpha" type="button" name="decrease" value="-">
</h4>
```